# Converting HTML page that takes input image to one that takes text

Tags: html

I have a reference HTML page that takes an image as input. 
https://gist.github.com/nikhilno1/353b4c9ee0ef9a18d244a514b526fb28

I want to convert it to take input as a text field instead. I want to keep the 'Analyze' button.

Simple stuff actually but I am not a UI guy.

I tried with this:

```
    <form action="{{ url_for('analyze') }}" method="post">
                            <input type="text" name="analyzeText">
                            <input type="submit">
                        </form>
```

Where I am using the submit button but it is returning "Not Found" with the URL being:

`http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000/%7B%7B%20url_for('analyze')%20%7D%7D`

Comment: i don't see anything wrong in here! maybe URL is wrong. What is your backend? js? ruby? c#? php? try writing another api-route and try to submit it again.

Comment: I am using python (starlette). When I changed to '<form action="/analyze" method="post">', it worked fine. How do I add 'url_for' correctly to this? Also for my own understanding I would like to make it work with a separate 'Analyze' button, like the way it is being done for the image.

Comment: Check your source in the browser. If action is `{{ url_for('analyze') }}` instead of a proper URL, then you need to make sure your view is properly handled by your renderer beforehand.

Comment: Unescaped http:// xx.xx.xx.xx:8000/{{ url_for('analyze,) }} looks like a non-sense - maybe some twice encoded (instead of en/decoded) verbatim string(?) Spaces and square brackets are probably wrong and should not be part of URL at all(?) Added one more space to prevent switching to link.

Comment: Yes action is {{ url_for('analyze') }}. I'm afraid I don't understand the second part (handling view etc). I am running a Uvicorn server. If I use a hard-coded url '/analyze', then it works fine.

Comment: xx.xx.xx.xx is the IP address which I masked.

Comment: Now I see, problem is in action you should have content of url_for('analyze') as action value not that strange string...